# Looping through a recursive array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I've got a recursive array. So the array below can go deeper and deeper.

```
0: "1"
1: [
    0: "2"
    1: [
        0: "3"
    ]
    2: [
        0: "4"
        1: [
            0: "5"
        ]
    ]
]
```

I want the output to be the path of all the values. So 123 and 1245.

How can this be done in a Javascript method?

Comment: I set a variable and fill it with `this.path += i` with `i` being the loop iterator. But I couldn't figure out how you can loop recursively. I tried some sample code of other people but that didn't really work for me.

Comment: Without any evidence that you tried to solve this problem yourself (no non-working code provided) I'm not going to answer for you, but I will give you a hint.  Recursive data structures can be processed with recursive algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a recursive method to flatten a recursive array.

Here's a pretty basic one:

```
var data = ["1",
[
    "2",
    [
        "3"
    ],
    [
        "4",
        [
            "5"
        ]
    ]
]];

var flattened = [];

function flatten(data, outputArray) {
    data.forEach(function (element){
        if(Array.isArray(element)) {
            flatten(element, outputArray);
        } else {
            outputArray.push(element);
        }
    });
}

flatten(data, flattened);
```

This should get you moving in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: how do you get 123 and 1245?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, but what you have presented looks more like an object. In such case it is quite easy to traverse through the nested object, eg.

```
var object = { 0: "1",
1: {
    0: "2",
    1: {
        0: "3"
    },
    2: {
        0: "4",
        1: {
            0: "5"
        }
    }
}};

console.info(object);

function traverse(obj) {
  obj.keys.forEach(function(key) {
    if (typeof(obj[key]) === 'object') {
      traverse(obj[key])
    } 
      else {
        //do something with the actual value
        console.log(obj[key])
      }
    })      
};

traverse(object)
```

Can you specify what did you mean with *I want the output to be the path of all the values*?

Comment: Remember that Javascript Arrays are objects with integer keys

Comment: how do you get 123 and 1245?

Answer (score 1):

You could try *lodash*:

```
_.flattenDeep([1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]]);
// => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#flattenDeep

but I'm not sure of your example data; you said an array but it looks (almost) like an object, in which case you'd have to first convert this to array. Again, *lodash* is your friend!

If you don't want to use *lodash* you could try something like this:

```
var results = [];
function flatten(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        flatten(item);
    }
    else {
        results.push(item);
    }
  })
}


flatten(data);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markwill/uLbcx77g/5/)

**Edit after comment by Nina Scholz**

It looks like the OP has an object with keys '0', '1', '2' etc, each of which may contain a recursive array. So the code above would have to be executed on the data associated with each key and the results appended to the value of the key to get 123, 1245 etc.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to not need a third party library for this

Comment: Of course, in which case it's a case for a recursive trawl of the array.

Comment: That's not what the OP said he wanted to do.

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood, the original exampe isn't an array so I've taken it to be illustrative, and the OP's title does say a recursive array.

Comment: how do you get 123 and 1245?

Comment: @NinaScholz - it's doesn't! I was just trying to show a recursive trawl of the array as the original example was a bit confusing. It looks like the OP has an object with keys '0', '1' etc each containing recursive arrays - I'll edit my answer to explain this.